# Show GIS data on website using automated qgis2web process

Tags: qgis, qgis2web

I managed to export my GIS map to my website through Qgis2Web. My map shows a daily view on a specific infestation of parasites in the poultry industry and I want this updated once a day, say at midnight CET.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We use a Focused question/Best answer model here. Please [Edit] your question to specify what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: Vote to reopen. This was closed unnecessarily. The OP asked *whether he could automate the desktop application, 'Qgis2Web'*. What about that is not focused and answerable? (FYI OP, to my knowledge the answer is "no", because you would need to automate the user's interaction with the GUI desktop application to create the output you need. As a general rule, if a task is performed in a GUI, but there is a desire to automate it, that's usually an indicator the task needs to be reevaluated for how it can be performed on a server without access to GUI software.)

Comment: OP, one more thought. Assuming Qgis2Web translates your source data from shapefiles (csv's, etc) to GeoJSON, you *might* be able to have your web server [run an ogr2ogr job](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/280653/4968) on those layers, translating them from their source format to [GeoJSON](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/geojson.html), then moving that GeoJSON output to the appropriate directory in your website. If this is all you need, just make sure the `ogr2ogr` job outputs the new file with the exact same name as the one it's replacing so your web map still recognizes it.

Comment: How are you gathering your data, and how is it stored locally.  As an alternative you  might find that a WMS or WFS would work better, you'd just need to mange updating the datasource.